# Find my web server running on the amazon linux

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services

when i typed "httpd -version" on terminal, prompted 'Server version: Apache/2.4.9 (Amazon)
Server built: Apr  1 2014 05:31:18' but
when i typed "service apache start/stop/restart" getting error 'apache: unrecognized service'
if i used "service httpd restart/etc" it works fine.
my question is how to find my runing server. ( httpd ? Lighttpd ? apache ? )

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Redhat based Linux variants, Apache is installed as the httpd service. Unfortunately, service naming is not entirely consistent across all Linux variants.